# Working with UITextFieldDelegate and a custom input container

Tags: swift3, uitextfielddelegate

In my current application, I have created a custom input container for the users to enter comments.  Please refer to the picture below.

[image]

The textfield is set as the delegate for UITextFieldDelegate, and I would like to work with shouldChangeCharactersInRange such that if the textField is empty, the sendButton is a gray color, and when there is at least 1 character filled in, it changes to blue.  However, currently with my code, the sendButton is blue to begin with, turns gray when 1 character is entered, and then back to blue when characters are greater than 1.  Kinda weird, trying to figure out why that is.  Here is my current relevant code:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if (textField.text?.characters.count)! > 0 {
        sendButton.setTitleColor(ovencloudBlueText, for: .normal)
    } else {
        sendButton.setTitleColor(newLoginGrayText, for: .normal)
    }
    return true
}
```

I know it's probably something simple that I'm missing. If this is a possible repeat, please let me know and I'll delete this post after checking out the reference link. Much thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `shouldChangeCharactersIn` **triggered before updating the ui**. So it begins with blue 'cause textfield is empty. And when you enter first character, `shouldChangeCharactersIn` works but if you check the `textField.text?.characters.count`at the moment, you will see it is `0` and `sendButton.setTitleColor(newLoginGrayText, for: .normal)` works. When you enter second character, `textField.text?.characters.count` comes `1` and it turns blue. You can do what you want like;

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let  char = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")

        if (isBackSpace == -92) {
            print("Backspace was pressed")
        }

        if (textField.text?.characters.count)! == 0 {
          sendButton.setTitleColor(ovencloudBlueText, for: .normal)
        }
        else if (textField.text?.characters.count)! == 1 && isBackSpace == -92 {
          sendButton.setTitleColor(newLoginGrayText, for: .normal)
        }

    return true
}
```

You will see it works

Comment: That's very interesting.  I wasn't aware of the flow of events related to the UI.  I have tried your code with a small modification on setting the button color to gray, and it does indeed work.  It's not obvious to me right away why (textField.text?.characters.count)! == 0 would allow for my desired effect of the button turning blue, but I'll look at it more deeply in the coming hours.  Much thanks for your help, and I hope this helps others as well!

Comment: Yeah, a similar case happened to me once. `shouldChangeCharactersIn` does not work the way i expect. `(textField.text?.characters.count)! == 0` works for blue because `textField.text?.characters.count` is zero only when first character entered. In all other cases it's different from 0. You are welcome by the way :) If you change your question's title like "shouldChangeCharactersIn is triggered strangely", question will reach more people i think :)